# How to get filtered in and out elements of array at one go in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I wonder if there is a precise way for getting filtered an unfiltered elements of an array in Javascript, I mean, like, in one go.

Currently, I use a logic like follows:

```js
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
const filterArray = ['a', 'b']

// I want to combine those two expressions somehow
const filteredInResult = myArray.filter(e => filterArray.includes(e))
const filteredOutResult = myArray.filter(e => !filterArray.includes(e))

console.log(filteredInResult)
console.log(filteredOutResult)
```

I felt like a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)-like way might already be there to achieve it, but anyway, I prefer asking you guys if there is a way for getting filtered in & out results in one shot.

**EDIT:** SO keeps alerting me if this question is similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1187518/4636715), but I used string comparison and `includes` for brewity above but the filtering expression may be more complex than that. So, the I must underline that the **focus of the question is not on difference of two string arrays**. I am leaving another example and hope the questions won't be merged :D

```js
// A more complex use case
const myArray = [
  {id: 1, value: 'a'},
  {id: 2, value: 'b'},
  {id: 3, value: 'c'},
  {id: 4, value: 'd'},
  {id: 5, value: 'e'},
]
const filterArray = ['a', 'b']

// I want to combine those two expressions somehow
const filteredInResult = myArray.filter(e => filterArray.includes(e.value))
const filteredOutResult = myArray.filter(e => !filterArray.includes(e.value))

console.log(filteredInResult)
console.log(filteredOutResult)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Realize the “one go” is contextual. In the answer and question example, the use of “includes” is doing a lookup (internal loop) with each iteration of the expressed loop. In no case would there ever be a “one go” solution.

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya Nope, I edited and added another use case to show that it is not always *the difference* of arrays with similar structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're worried about iterating twice over the `myArray`, you might *first* consider reducing the computational complexity. Because each iteration of the loops calls `Array.prototype.includes`, and the complexity of `Array.prototype.includes` is `O(n)`, your code has an overall complexity of `O(n ^ 2)`. (outer loop: `O(n)` * inner loop: `O(n)`). So, consider fixing that first: use a Set and `Set.has`, an `O(1)` operation, instead of an array and `.includes`. This is assuming that your actual `filterArray` is large enough that computational complexity is something to worry about - sets *do* have a bit of an overhead cost.

As for the other (main) part of the question, one option is to create the two result arrays outside, then push to the appropriate one while iterating:

```js
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
const filterArray = new Set(['a', 'b'])

const filteredInResult = [];
const filteredOutResult = [];
for (const e of myArray) {
  (filterArray.has(e) ? filteredInResult : filteredOutResult).push(e);
}
console.log(filteredInResult)
console.log(filteredOutResult)
```

Could also use `reduce`, though I don't think it looks very good:

```js
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
const filterArray = new Set(['a', 'b'])

const { filteredInResult, filteredOutResult } = myArray.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[filterArray.has(e) ? 'filteredInResult' : 'filteredOutResult'].push(e);
  return a;
}, { filteredInResult: [], filteredOutResult: [] });

console.log(filteredInResult)
console.log(filteredOutResult)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `.reduce()` instead of `.filter()`, where you use the (numeric) boolean value of `includes()` as the index for your accumilator like so:

```js
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const filterArray = ['a', 'b'];

const [fOut, fIn] = myArray.reduce((a, n) => {
  a[+filterArray.includes(n)].push(n); 
  return a;
}, [[], []]);

console.log(fIn);
console.log(fOut);
```

Answer (score 3):

I could not destruct but this seems to be simpler to read than the reduce offered elsewhere

```js
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
const filterArray = ['a', 'b']
let filteredOutResult = [];

const filteredInResult = myArray.filter(item => { 
   if (filterArray.includes(item)) return item; 
   filteredOutResult.push(item); 
});

console.log(filteredInResult,filteredOutResult)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with ramda's [partition](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#partition).

```js
const
    array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    filter = ['a', 'b'],
    [filteredInResult, filteredOutResult] = R.partition(v => filter.includes(v), array);

console.log(...filteredInResult); // a b
console.log(...filteredOutResult) // c d e
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ramda/latest/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One native answer is to use `Array#reduce`:

```js
const { in, out } = myArr.reduce((acc, v) => {
  (filterArray.includes(v) ? acc.in : acc.out).push(v);
  return acc;
}, { in: [], out: [] });
```

And then destructure the returned object