# How to return conditional arrays from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve the below in a cleaner/more efficient way?

```js
const data = [
    { active: false },
    { active: false },
    { active: true },
    { active: false },
    { active: true },
]

const split = (data) => {
    const activeData = data.filter(({active}) => active).map(element => 1)
    const inactiveData = data.filter(({active}) => !active).map(element => 0)

    return [
        activeData,
        inactiveData,
    ]
}

console.log(split(data))
```

The problem here, I think, is that this approach is not efficient, because it's filtering and mapping through the same array twice. Is there a way to do it just once?

Comment: do you want only ones and zeros? please add the wanted result.

Comment: Define data just with array: `[false, false, true, false, true]`

Comment: The result is not particularly important, it could be mapped to anything. I'm just asking if it's possible to avoid cycling through the same array twice, as in the example. The only requirement here, is that `data` is an array of objects.

Comment: Cleaner will most likely be Opinion-based...

Comment: Use a `for..of` loop and push to 2 different arrays based on an `if` condition.

Comment: @adiga Yeah, that was only approach that I could think of, to avoid cycling twice through the array

Comment: @MikeK [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050741/how-to-get-filtered-in-and-out-elements-of-array-at-one-go-in-javascript/) is related, it does the filtering in one iteration, but not the mapping, you could probably repurpose one of the solutions though to incorporate the mapping part.

Comment: instead of `.map()` you can use `.fill(1)` and `.fill(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Unless your array is immense, it's not going to make any difference. However you could indeed do this in one pass through the array:

```js
    const split = (data) =>
      data.reduce((rv, entry) => 
        (rv[+!entry.active].push(+entry.active), rv)
      , [[], []]);
      
    console.log(split([{active: true}, {active: false}, {active: false}]))
```

The `+` operators convert the boolean values to numbers (0 or 1). The "rv" parameter to the `.reduce()` callback is the "return value", or the accumulator into which the `.reduce()` callback builds up the result. In this code, the callback uses the "active" flag (negated) to pick either the first array (index 0) or the second array (index 1) in the accumulator "array of arrays".  The value pushed into the chosen array is then either 0 or 1, again obtained from the "active" value by converting it to a number.

Comment: This an interesting approach and seems to be what I'm looking for. Can you please elaborate what's going on here? Does `rv` here refer to both of the initial arrays of the reducer? Also, it doesn't seem to work without the cast number (doing `(rv[+!entry.active].push(+entry.active), rv)` seems to crash it), does this mean it'll only work with numbers and not boolean values, for example?

Comment: @MikeK I'll add a little explanation to the answer; it's basically what `.reduce()` is all about.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop and reduce the array using an object as target.

```js
const
    data = [{ active: false }, { active: false }, { active: true }, { active: false }, { active: true }],
    { true: activeData, false: inactiveData } = data.reduce((r, { active }) =>
        (r[active].push(+active), r),
        { true: [], false: [] }
    );

console.log(activeData);
console.log(inactiveData);
```

Comment: This only returns one array, is it possible to return two, as in the OP approach?

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have a clean way to do it, however using multiple array functions requires more loops over the data.

Reduce will allow us to do this just once.

```js
const data = [
    { active: false },
    { active: false },
    { active: true },
    { active: false },
    { active: true },
]

const split = (data) =>
  data.reduce((acc, {active}) => acc[+!active].push(+active) && acc, [[],[]])

console.log(split(data))
```

Comment: Is `acc` here always both of the arrays? If so, how do you determine which one to push to, if you're always just pushing to the `acc`?

Comment: This is just another variation of what @Pointy did.